# UnexpectedTypeException in Symfony2 forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
class Person
{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        if(empty($this->name)) {
            return '';
        }
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

With a normal `PersonType` form:

```
class PersonType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, ...)
         $build->add('name', 'text');
     }
}
```

When I try to build the form in the controller via Symfony's

`$this->createForm(new PersonType(), new Person());`

I get the error:

`Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string" given in Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 49`

I have this for several fields, I figure Symfony2 does not regard an empty string `''` as empty.
So what can I do? Create a model transformer for every field in my form?... 
That would seem a little too much. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

For the record if I just return the null value when it's not set such as `return $this->name;` and without checking if `$this->name` is empty error goes away and the form is properly rendered as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more details about this error?

Comment: So the form is being rendered even though you use 'Name' (instead of 'name') field in `buildForm` method?

Comment: Copy/past your error in google, got this
https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle/issues/54
It seems you should set a default option to your form, to tell him hes working with your Person class.

Comment: @bartek There's no typos, but yes even though I've never tried to do that. Of course it wouldn't be able to work with the information after the form is submitted. :)

Comment: @bartek I have set the default data class as `Person`. I don't think that resolves the issue.

Comment: add "return $this;" to your setName function, and additionaly change ->add("Name" to ->add("name"

Comment: @Tek last try... so maybe try to cast `''` as string: `return (string) '';` or `return sprintf('%s', '');`

Comment: @johnSmith Sorry, I had that typo in the question but not the code. However this happens to every field I try to return `''` via a `get`.

Comment: @Tek Can you show us how do you define your entity? I suppose you use yml for that

Comment: @bartek No, that entity is defined as you see it there. It's only a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not returning an empty string and left it returning nulls for it to work.

Instead I used Symfony2's `empty_data` http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it work like this :

```
public function getName()
{
    if(empty($this->name)) {
       $this->name('');
    }
    return $this->name;
}
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't think I'm allowed to have empty strings. Which is weird because I don't know why I'm allowed to have strings, just not empty ones. Edit: Actually, I take that back. I'm allowed to have strings after the form is processed, but not before the form is submitted.